# R Flexdashboard: Navigation captions don't show up in hidden storyboard

Tags: r, storyboard, flexdashboard

I am building a Flexdashboard. On the start page there should be links leading to several hidden storyboard (i.e. so that the storyboards do not show up in the navigation bar at the top).

However, **it appears that using {.hidden} on a storyboard page interferes with the navigation captions**: only the first caption of three is visible: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqzKi.png)

Using the arrows one can still access all three graphs but without the captions.

Does anybody know how to make hidden storyboard-pages work?

I am using R 4.2.0; Flexdashboard 0.5.2; RStudio 2022.02.1
Reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```

Start page
===========================================================
[Link](#storyboard)

Storyboard{.storyboard .hidden}
===========================================================

### Chart A
```{r}
boxplot(mtcars$mpg)
```

### Chart B
```{r}
boxplot(mtcars$cyl)
```

### Chart C
```{r}
boxplot(mtcars$hp)
```
````